# jQuery json dictionary solution

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Would like to handle translation with json and jquery. The problem i'm facing is how to get values and output its parameter if no such translation value exists.

Hard to explain, will try.

dict['Total Amount'] would for example return "My total amount" in another language, if that is what the key holds. But if I would send dict['Max Score'] and key "Max Score" doesn't exist it should write Max Score instead.

I have no idea how to accomplish this. Perhaps a json object would work? Really need help thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) to get an idea of the correct terminology. JSON is something very different than JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

How you store your data, e.g. as JSON, doesn't matter for this problem. Assuming you are having an object, such as

```
var de = {
   'hello': 'hallo'
};
```

for a language, you can create a function that accepts a dictionary and a phrase to look up. Test if the phrase exists and if it doesn't, return the phrase itself:

```
function lookup(phrase, dict) {
    if (dict.hasOwnProperty(phrase)) {
        return dict[phrase];
    }
    return phrase;
}

var translation = lookup('bye', de);
```

**References**: [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

Its `array` not `json object` and you had not added key `Max Score` in `dict` array, try to `assign` `Max Score key` like,

```
var dict=[];
dict['Total Amount'] ='My total amount';
alert(dict['Total Amount'] ,dict['Max Score']);// dict['Max Score'] = blank/undefined
dict['Max Score'] ='Max Score';
alert(dict['Max Score']);// alerts Max Score
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YnLw7/)

If you use `json` and get any `key` by `.` then don't use `space` in a key, otherwise you can't be able to get the appropriate result.

Comment: I think he wants to allow checking for inexisting keys, (that's the point of a dictionary) :D